# Discordbot with discord.py doesn`t deletes messages with command ctx.channel.purge(*amount*)

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.7

I got the problem, that when I use the purge command in my Bot using discord.py rewriting method, it doesn't work. What I mean by that is that when I run the code, and then write 'clear' in the discord channel, it simply doesn't deletes the given amount of messages, and it also doesn't raises an error. I've also tried to put print('test') in the definition, but then it only prints test...

That is the Code I used to do this:

```
@client.command
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the proper use of `@client.command` is `@client.command()`. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Oh, that fixed it.. I'm stupid.. Thank you!